# Create an order in admin panel with a new product type

Tags: magento2, product, orders, admin-panel, product-type

I created a new product type like "License Product" extend from "Virtual Product".
I can place an order with this product type in frontend, but i can't add this product to order in backend.

Any help will be appreciated.

This is my code:

**Setup/InstallData.php**

```
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);


        $fieldList = [
            'price',
            'special_price',
            'special_from_date',
            'special_to_date',
            'minimal_price',
            'cost',
            'tier_price',
            'weight',
        ];

        foreach ($fieldList as $field) {
            $applyTo = explode(
               ',',
               $eavSetup->getAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, $field, 'apply_to')
        );
        if (!in_array('license', $applyTo)) {
            $applyTo[] = 'license';
            $eavSetup->updateAttribute(
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
                $field,
                'apply_to',
                implode(',', $applyTo)
            );
        }
    }
  }
}
```

**etc/product_types.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/product_types.xsd">
<type name="license" label="License Product" modelInstance="Demo\ProductType\Model\Product\Type\License"
      composite="false" isQty="true" canUseQtyDecimals="false" sortOrder="70">
    <priceModel instance="Demo\ProductType\Model\Product\Type\Price"/>
    <customAttributes>
        <attribute name="refundable" value="true"/>
        <attribute name="is_real_product" value="false"/>
    </customAttributes>
</type>
```

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: Ex: I created a new product with type "License Product" and it have id as 2000. But when i  can't find this product when i want add  it to an orders in admin panel.

Answer (score 4):

as far as I see, when the collection of available product types is prepared, the list is fetched from `Magento\Sales\Model\Config::getAvailableProductTypes()` which in turns searches for XML configuration under `order/available_product_types` nodes.

In other words: did you define a `sales.xml` file under your module's `etc` folder made like this?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Sales:etc/sales.xsd">
    <order>
        <available_product_type name="license"/>
    </order>
</config>
```

Hope it throws some light.

Comment: Glad it was helpful! Thank you for the points.